# Simple HTML page to display download links - APK Links not working?

Tags: html, web, hyperlink

I have created a simple html page called index.htm with download links for easy access.

the following simple code does this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Downloads</h1>

<p>

<a href="nixagent.apk">SureMDM</a>

<br>
<br>

<a href="word.apk">Word</a>

<br>
<br>

<a href="excel.apk">Excel</a>

<br>
<br>

<a href="TeamViewer_Host_Setup.exe">Remote Support</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

in the same location as the index.htm i have all the APK files as well as the teamviewer .exe file

My problem however is that the links for the APK files do not work. I get the error 404 - File or directory not found.

However the link for the teamviewer .exe at the bottom does work. It is interesting to note that the APK files are in the same exact same location as the working .exe

Comment: This should work. Are you sure that the  APK files are in the same folder as your inde.html file? and is it correct spelled the file name?

Comment: that's what i thought! i can confirm they are in the same folder, and the names are correct. I've tried multiple file types, exe, jpg etc it just seems to be a problem with APK files!

Comment: what is interesting is that if i open the page through the domain, e.g. www.testwebsite.domain/indexhtm it does not work, but if i access it via the file path e,g, C:/testwebsite/index.htm then these APK links work. any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Do you get an error message? Are you sure that the APK is uploaded on the server? Do you have a link to your domain so we can test it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It takes you to a page 404 - file or directory not found. The APK files are in the exact same location as the working .exe file at the bottom. www.logmeinhpc.com if you would like to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are running this on an Windows Server.
Try to add the type **APK** to your **IIS MIME Types**.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Selection "MIME Type" feature
3. Add Mime Type
4. Insert into File type Extension: "**.apk**"
5. Insert into MIME type: "**application/vnd.android.package-archive**"
6. Hit OK
7. Restart Server

Comment: Sorry for the late response, only just got round getting back onto this. This worked perfectly, thanks!